# Bootstrap tooltip makes element flicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

In my application, I use the bootstrap tooltips but whenever I hover over a button that uses tooltips one of my elements starts flickering. What could cause this issue?

This is how I create the tooltip:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement:"auto"});
```

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/oLkuat84/10/

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a browser issue.  Your JS works with no flicker on OSX->Firefox and OSX->Chrome but has that horrible red/blue flicker in OSX->Safari (where does the blue come from?)

You can isolate the problem by removing the `top` and `left` attributes from the `style-switcher-btn-3` class.

From what I can gather: it's that safari is re-rendering the two fixed-position items (the tooltip and the `style-switcher-btn-3`) and this cases the flicker.  Where the blue colouring comes from I have no idea.

If at all possible, try to make that button grouping not a `position:fixed`.

Comment: Its is weird, I have this issue in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE.